# how to create r matrix or table from data

Tags: r, statistics

My data format in csv is the following. I would like to create a matrix for heatmap using this file. R gglot i am going to use.

```
A B     C
1 apple 3
2 book  5
4 bag   1
9 desk  4
10 apple 8
11 book 66
14 desk 2
```

I would like to create a matrix for heatmap using that above file.

```
       1  2  4  9  10  11  14
apple  3  0  0  0  8   0   0
book   0  5  0  0  0   66   0
bag    0  0  1  0  0   0   0
desk   0  0  0  4  0   0   2
```

i have another column in initial file for ordering.

```
 
A B     C     D
1 apple 3     4
2 book  5     1
4 bag   1     2
9 desk  4     3
10 apple 8    4
11 book 66    1
14 desk 2     3
```

how can i order my matrix due to this D ordering column? or i would like to order by sum of 1-14 column.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xtabs`.

```
d <- read.delim(textConnection("
A B C
1 apple 3
2 book 5
4 bag 1
9 desk 4
10 apple 8
11 book 66
14 desk 2
"), sep=" ")

xtabs(C ~ B + A, d)

       A
B        1  2  4  9 10 11 14
         0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  apple  3  0  0  0  8  0  0
  bag    0  0  1  0  0  0  0
  book   0  5  0  0  0 66  0
  desk   0  0  0  4  0  0  2
```

Comment: i need to order this matrix,  i have extra column for ordering. check the my question i will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `read.table`. You can get the help for choosing the correct parameters by typing `?read.table` into your R-GUI.

Comment: yes i used read.table. but it is not like the matrix i showed above. from my table how can create matrix like above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the read.delim part from Vincent above and a reshape approach. Not as elegant...

```
d <- read.delim(textConnection("
A B C
1 apple 3
2 book 5
4 bag 1
9 desk 4
10 apple 8
11 book 66
14 desk 2
"), sep=" ")

Var1 <- rep(d[,1], d[,3])
Var2 <- rep(d[,2], d[,3])
d <- data.frame(Var1=Var1, Var2=Var2)
d <- cast(melt(d), Var2~value)

> d
   Var2 1 2 4 9 10 11 14
1 apple 3 0 0 0  8  0  0
2   bag 0 0 1 0  0  0  0
3  book 0 5 0 0  0 66  0
4  desk 0 0 0 4  0  0  2
```

Comment: Here is a shorter `reshape` solution, with the initial data.frame: `dcast( d, B ~ A, fill=0 )`.